# Use input function two get multiple inputs in a single line (Python)

Tags: python

to initialize a list and read the value of n, followed by n lines of command.
I tried by creating a empty list first and then initializing it to accept commands and got output as.

```
10
append
5
append
6
append
7
insert
3 8
print
[5, 6, 7, 8]
sort
print
[5, 6, 7, 8]
reverse
append
10
print
[8, 7, 6, 5, 10]

But, how to obtain command and values on the same line i.e
10
append 5
append 6
append 7
insert 3 8
print
[5,6,7,8]
reverse
append 10
print
[8,7,6,5,10]
```

Comment: Could you please add a code sample on what you are trying to achieve? Are you reading from the command line?

Comment: list=[]
    N=int(input())
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        x=input()  #"enter command"
        if (x=="insert"):
            y,z=input().split() #"enter position and value: "
            y,z=[int(y),int(z)]
            list.insert(y,z)
        elif (x=="append"):
            z=int(input())  #"enter value: "
            list.append(z)

Answer (score 1):

you would need to read each line and split it manually and then append it to the list . then it would work

something like this 
`a,b = raw_input().strip().split(' ')`